# OnClickListner crashes the program

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm trying to get a text from `EditText`and add it to a `ListView` on a `Button` click. But `onclicklistner` stops my application. 
Here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ChatFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//*
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_msg);
            data.add(mValue.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,R.layout.list_item_available,R.id.listview_availabe_textview,data );
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

* - debugger stops here.

log says

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at albz.apostle.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:48)
```

thank you

Comment: Are you sure you have `btn_send` in your `activity_chat.xml`?

Comment: Do you initialize data ? `data = new ArrayList<String>;`

Comment: please post your layout. my guess is there is no button with the id btn_send in your layout.

Comment: sorry about the trouble it was a simple misunderstanding from my side I used the wrong button thanks M D.

Comment: Sorry every one about it my bad

Comment: @AlbinShaji Ohhhh very bad... Change it and enjoy coding cheers!!!!1 budy!!!!!1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define click listener in fragment if the view(button) is present in fragment layout.